# phpinfo() blank after upgrade

Tags: apache2

I have just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 18 and PHP 8.0

I have checked using php -v and it reports 8.0 but phpinfo() was reporting 7.2

I purged 7.2, rebooted and now phpinfo() is simply showing the php instruction itself and not the php version.

I understand that this is to do with php_mod (or I believe it is) but I cannot seem to get this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me.

Tonight seems to be a night of posting and emailing only for the system to behave itself!

phpinfo() is now reporting 8.0.10

Though I had cleared the browser cache and rebooted apache, there appears to have been a delay.